# Как выполнить загрузку данных при прокрутке RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, recyclerview, firebase

Где ошибка в коде ? Должно загружаться 10 старых сообщений при прокрутке вниз

```
 binding.recyclerViewChat.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
            if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                isScrolling = true
            }
        }

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
            if (dy < 0) {
                isScrolling = false
                countMessages += 10
                MESSAGES.child(senderRoom).addChildEventListener(AppChildEventListener {
                    val chats = it.getValue(ChatsModel::class.java)
                    adapter.addItem(chats!!, smoothScrollToPosition)
                })
            }
        }
    })
```